# Emacs only runs GUI when not sudo

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, sudo, xauth

I have installed emacs from ubuntu's software center and everything seems to work fine except for `sudo emacs` which instead of running the gui version, gives error `No protocol specified Display :0 unavailable, simulating -nw` and then runs in the terminal.

using `emacs` (w/out `sudo`) I do not see such an error, the gui version runs fine but the extensions I want to use are then blocked by permissions.

I am using ubuntu 17.10 fresh install with all the updates.

I have tried using `emacs -d localhost:0.0` but this gives error `Display localhost:0.0 can't be opened`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your error

This is not emacs-specific.
The problem is that your non-root user runs X which does not give permissions to your root user.
Try `sudo xterm` and you will get the same error.

This question has been answered on Unix twice:

- [ssh and sudo but no $DISPLAY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241394/31443)
- [Why can't I run GUI apps from 'root': “No protocol specified”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118811/31443)

## Emacs can do better!

However, please note that an Emacs user would not run Emacs under sudo but rather [sudo](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Inline-methods.html#index-method-sudo-28) under [Emacs/Tramp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/).

See [the detailed SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177687/850781).

Comment: I was able to fix my problem using `xhost si:localuser:root` following the advice in the comment by Karl Richter [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified). I do not see this on the page you linked, so I cannot say definitively that what you proposed would accomplish the same thing --but maybe you could expand your answer to say why these are/are not equivalent?

Comment: unfortunately I am finding this solution disappears after restart. I have tried the .Xauthority suggestions but none of these work, trying `sudo xauth generate :0 . trusted` to generate a proper .Xauthority does not work --a very similiar error occurs. So for the meantime I am just adding `xhost si:localuser:root > /dev/null` to my `.bashrc`

Comment: @skyfire: I urge you to use Emacs/Tramp.